# How do I type the infinity symbol in MacTex?

Tags: symbols

```
\item Obtain the one-to-one function $f_1$ and $f_2$ by cutting the graph of $f$ at 
      a certain point ($x_1$, $y_1$) so that domain of ($f_1$)=($-∞$ , $x_1$] and 
      domain ($f_2$)=[$x_1$,$+∞$)
```

Comment: You need `\infty`

Comment: When using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX as your typesetter, you need to include the »[unicode-math](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math)« package.

Comment: Just a general tip: It's safter to use `\(f_1\)` and `\[f_1\]` than `$f_1$` and `$$f_1$$`. For more information, see this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to or read about it in l2tabu.

Comment: @SamWhited -- I would disagree with you on the claim that there's a generic safety related advantage to using `\( ... \)` rather than `$ ... $` to delimit inline math. Indeed, since `\(`and `\)` are not "robust" commands (in the LaTeX sense of the word "robust"), it's perilous to use them in the arguments of "moving" commands; no such difficulties arise with `$`. Note that the link you provide regards the use of `$$` -- a rather different matter.

Comment: @Mico Fair point; l2tabu doesn't mention `\(\)` either, though I had thought it talked about line spacing a bit. Oh well, ignore my comment (although I'd still go with the LaTeX way unless you need to put it in a moving argument for some reason).

Answer (score 39):

A better style is:

Obtain the one-to-one function `$f_1$` and `$f_2$` by cutting the graph of `$f$` at 
      a certain point `$(x_1, y_1)$` so that domain of `$(f_1)=(-\infty , x_1]$` and 
      domain `$(f_2)=[x_1,+\infty)$`

(Please compare the obtained spacing).

Answer (score 19):

If you are still faced with such a problem, as the last resort, you can use the rotated eight as follows.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\infinity{\rotatebox{90}{8}}
\begin{document}
$(-\infinity, x_1]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Only meticulous readers will spot the difference.

Comment: Every good math font has the symbol corresponding to `\infty`.

Comment: @egreg: Yes. It is just for emergency purposes. :-)

Comment: Some fonts have a `\infty` that really looks like a rotated 8 instead of a distinct design.